# disppeared recession bar when copy as metafile

Tags: r, matlab, eps, metafile

I am using ggplot to add recession bars in Rstudio. However, when I copy it as metafile and paste, the bars disappear. I also found this problem in matlab using recessionplot when copying as eps.

The following is my code.

```
bplot2 <- ggplot(yfit6.df, aes(x=date, y=yfit6,group = 1)) +
  scale_x_yearqtr(limits = c(min(yfit6.df$date), max(yfit6.df$date)),
                  format = "%YQ%q")+
  ylim(c(0,1))+geom_line(aes(y=yfit6.df$yfit6), colour = 'grey40',size=0.8) +
  ylab("Recession probability") +
  ggtitle("6 Month Ahead In-sample Forecasts")+theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.9, face="bold",size=20),text = element_text(size=17))
print(bplot2)
###add recession bar###
bplot2<-bplot2+geom_area(data=as.data.frame(y6),aes(x=yfit6.df$date, y=y6),alpha=0.2)
print(bplot2)
```

The nomal graph looks like this [image]

However, when I copy it as metafile and paste, it is like this [image]

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “copy it as metafile”? And where do you paste it?

Comment: I clicked export---copy to clipboard---copy as metafile. The normal is copy as bitmap. I pasted it in a powerpoint file. Thanks

Comment: Interesting, this option doesn’t exist for me — it’s probably Windows-only. At any rate, a Windows Metafile is *not* a bitmap. It’s more akin to a vector graphic. The problem is that (as far as I know) PowerPoint never supported this format fully and PowerPoint furthermore has some known bugs regarding rescaling of vector graphics. You should export and include a high-resolution bitmap instead.

Comment: Thanks konrad.  In rstudio the option is at the bottom right plot window. Maybe it is the problem of powerpoint. What interesting is that I use a similar command in matlab and save it as eps, but when I add the graph in latex, the recession shade covers all the lines, which is really weird as latex should fully support eps and this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

The EPS files generated by R do not include transparency data, see [this prior question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440254)

I use the following workaround to generate EPS:

```
library(grDevices)
cairo_ps(filename='Figure.eps', width=7, height=5)
last_plot()
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks patrick. It works!

Comment: @Rong Great!  Feel free to upvote the question and answer.